# "des jaloux" and "des envieux" from Le Comte de Monte-Cristo

Tags: articles, adjectifs

This post is on *des jaloux* and *des envieux* as found in this passage from [*Le Comte de Monte-Cristo*, chapter 7](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_Comte_de_Monte-Cristo/Chapitre_7).

Dantès, the hero of the novel, has been arrested and is being questioned by Villefort, a public prosecutor.

> — Monsieur, dit Villefort, vous connaissez-vous quelques ennemis ?
>     — Des ennemis à moi, dit Dantès : j’ai le bonheur d’être trop peu de chose pour que ma position m’en ait fait. Quant à mon caractère, un peu vif peut-être, j’ai toujours essayé de l’adoucir envers mes subordonnés. J’ai dix ou douze matelots sous mes ordres : qu’on les interroge, Monsieur, et ils vous diront qu’ils m’aiment et me respectent, non pas comme un père, je suis trop jeune pour cela, mais comme un frère aîné.
>     — Mais, à défaut d’ennemis, peut-être avez-vous **des jaloux** : vous allez être nommé capitaine à dix-neuf ans, ce qui est un poste élevé dans votre état ; vous allez épouser une jolie femme qui vous aime, ce qui est un bonheur rare dans tous les états de la terre ; ces deux préférences du destin ont pu vous faire **des envieux**.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Do the expressions mean 'some jealous ones (people)' and 'some envious ones'?
2. Is there a noun that is implicit at the end?  If one had to supply it, what would it be? E.g., *hommes*, *personnes*?
3. If there is an implicit noun at the end, I then recall this bit of grammar (from *Oxford French Grammar* (1991)):

   > The plural indefinite artcle **des** becomes **de** (d' before a vowel or **h** 'mute') when the noun following is preceded by an adjective:
   >     **j'ai eu d'incroyables difficultés**, *I've had unbelievable difficulties*
   >   This rule is often ignored where the meaning of the phrase centers on the noun rather than the adjective:
   >     **des jolies filles**, *pretty girls*
   >   It is always ignored where the adjective + noun pair forms a set expression:
   >     **des petits pois**, *peas*
   >     **des petits pains**, *bread rolls*

   Here none of the exceptions would apply.  (Specifically the emphasis would rather be on the adjective as the noun is not even expressed.)  Should I then understand that there exists a third exception to the effect that *des* remains *des* when the noun has been suppressed?
4. How common is it to say *des* + plural adjective to mean 'people that have the attribute denoted by the adjective'? Could it even be used as the subject of a clause? Please give examples if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Jaloux* and *envieux* indeed mean "jealous/envious persons" but are used as substantives here so there is no suppressed noun.

Many descriptive adjectives can be nominalized and have been granted the status of nouns:

> *Tu es entouré de **blondes***.
>
> *Tu arrives dans la cour des **grands***.

same for *ambitieux*, *avare*, *timide*, *méchant*, *gentil*...

Some, like *jaloux* and *envieux*, are not officially nouns but can nevertheless be nominalized, like for example *sales*, *lâches* and *sauvages*.

Answer (score 1):

Q.2 : *Implicit noun* ?

In your particular case (jaloux, envieux) : **yes**! There is some implicit noun.
**Because** *jaloux* and *envieux* are adjectives being nominalized. As such, they do carry some noun (the referent) implicitly.

Do not generalize to other adjectives such as some suggested in another answer :

- *blond* IS an adjective but also a noun per se. This is indeed (in the examples given) **not** the adjective being nominalized.
  Because of the leading article, the noun is being used. => no implicit noun.
- The same with *avare*, *timide*

You can find the categories of the words in [Dictionnaire de l'Académie](https://academie.atilf.fr/).

e.g. ENVIEUX, -EUSE **adj**. / BLOND, BLONDE **adj. et n.**